# How to escape a newline character in a string literal in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, escaping

In my template, I want to check if a string stored in a variable contains a newline. However, I haven't found a way to escape the newline character in the string literal used in the check. The obvious

```
{% if "\n" in description %}
...
{% endif %}
```

does not work, seems to auto-escape the "\".

Of course I can always implement a simple custom filter or model method, but I thought there had to be an easier way. Searching for this on the web is hard as "escaping" in the context of Django templates is mostly concerned with escaping HTML, not string characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a key in the context dict being passed to your template, call it `newline` perhaps, with a value of `"\n"`.  You could then do things like `{% if newline in description %}` in your template.

EDIT: I've checked the Django source, there really isn't a built-in way to do this.  The only escape sequences that are processed in template string literals are backslash-quote and double-backslash.

Comment: This would be a valid workaround, although it requires changing the view code or introducing a context processor (which would seem overkill to me), therefore not easily possible in all scenarios. Thanks for digging into the Django code, interesting that they would hard-code two escape characters but not include \n.